# Codeigniter doesn't upload video files

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with the function for upload video and images. I can upload images but not video I don' know why. In the and more code for controller and form.

Code in user_models php:

```
function newp($title,$post,$image,$video,$cat){
$id=$this->session->userdata('userid');

if($video!="")

{
    $data=array(
    'userid'=>$id,
    'title'=>$title,
    'forumpost'=>$post,
    'categoryid'=>$cat,
    'videourl'=>$video
    );
}
```

Image:

```
else if($image!=""){
    $data=array(
    'userid'=>$id,
    'title'=>$title,
    'forumpost'=>$post,
    'categoryid'=>$cat,
    'imageurl'=>$image
    );
}else{
    $data=array(
    'userid'=>$id,
    'title'=>$title,
    'forumpost'=>$post,
    'categoryid'=>$cat,


    );}
   $this->db->insert('forum',$data);
  }
  }
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/forum/newpk">
<div style="float:left;width: 95%;margin-top:5px;margin-left: 15px">
<h3> Add A Post</h3>
<div class="list-group" >
<input type="text" required name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title of the Post">
</div>

<div class="list-group">
<textarea name="post" class="form-control" style="min-height: 150px;" placeholder="Post">     
    </textarea>

    </div>

    <div class="list-group">
    <span style="float:left;display:inline-block;"><p style="font-size:15px">Video File</p>    <input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*" /></span>
    <p style="font-size:15px;margin-left:10%;width: 32px;display:inline-block;">OR</p>
```

Image File

```
   </div>
   <div class="listgroup">
To which category it belongs
<select name="cat"><?php foreach($cato as $cat){ ?><option name="cat" value="<?php echo $cat->categoryid;?>"><?php echo $cat->categoryname;?></option><?php }?></select>




  </div>


  <div class="list-group" style="margin-top: 70px;margin-left: 35%;">
<button type="submit" style="width: 159px;height: 47px;line-height: 2.3;font-size: 17px;"  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

  </div>

  </div>

  </form>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function newpk(){



    if($this->session->userdata('userid')){
$title=$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('title'));
$post=$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('post'));
    $cat=$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('cat'));

     if($cat=="" || $post=="" || $title=="")
    {
     echo "Required field cannot be empty";
    die();

     }

 $themepicid="";

    $this->load->model('forum_model');
```

Video part:

```
if(isset($_FILES['video']) && $_FILES['video']['size']>0){
    $pktid=$this->idGenerator();

     $pathh='assets/video/';
$themepicid=$this->session->userdata('userid');
$type= pathinfo($_FILES['video']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$pic=$themepicid;
$themepicid=$themepicid.$pktid.".".$type;
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $pathh.$themepicid);

    $image="";
    $this->forum_model->newp($title,$post,$image,$themepicid,$cat); // How the forum likes
```

Image part:

```
    }
else if(isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size']>0){
    $pathh='assets/images/';
$themepicid=$this->session->userdata('userid');
$type= pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $pktid=$this->idGenerator();

$pic=$themepicid;
$themepicid=$themepicid.$pktid.".".$type;


            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $pathh.$themepicid);

    $image="";
    $this->forum_model->newp($title,$post,$themepicid,$image,$cat);

}
else{

   $image="";
   $this->forum_model->newp($title,$post,$image,$image,$cat);

}


   redirect('index.php/forum','refresh');


    } 
else{

redirect('index.php/user','refresh');
    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Some help troubleshooting would be nice.
can you var_dump all the variables when you try to post a video? 

also this has nothing to do with uploading files, It's about storing them in a database. 

In anyway, more troubleshooting is needed.

Comment: I add some more code I hope you can understand now what is the problem. Thanks @Patrick

Comment: I'm sorry that's alot of badly formatted code go to go through, Can you pinpoint the problem itself? 

If something isn't loaded, var_dump it and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your video size larger than max size upload config in php.ini

You can use upload library from CI, it's easy to use and help you prevent error

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

If you using upload lib of CI, dont forget config allowed types

Comment: php.ini is configuration file of server

Comment: I have no access to that file on my server this is a school server.

Comment: create php file and write to it <?php phpinfo(); ?>

then run it, search for constant upload_max_filesize , then you can upload file smaller size than this size